# First principle of thermodynamics vs classical mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy, work

please I need clarification about the first principle of thermodynamics, it's general statement is:

$$\Delta U + \Delta \text{KE} + \Delta \text{PE}= W + Q .$$

Supposing that: $ΔU = 0$ and $Q = 0$, then: 
$\Delta \text{KE} + \Delta \text{PE}= W$ (of total forces).

But, We know from classical mechanics that :$\Delta \text{KE} + \Delta \text{PE}= W$(of non conservative forces)

We get : $W$(of non conservative forces)$= W$(of total forces)

WHICH IS ABSURD!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is absurd here.

When writing $$\Delta U+\Delta \text{KE} +\Delta \text{PE}=W+Q$$ the work term $W$ is work done by non-conservative forces as well as work done by any external conservative forces you haven't included in $\Delta \text{PE}$. This is also true in your "classical mechanics" expression $$\Delta \text{KE}+\Delta \text{PE}=W$$

The $W$ here is not "net work done by all forces". This is only the case in your "classical mechanics" sense using the work energy theorem of $W_\text{net}=\Delta \text{KE}$. Where now you are talking about the work done by all forces.

So, really you have "W(of non conservative forces)= W(of non conservative forces)" which, of course, is fine.